# Facebook Instant Article with (not set) in Google Analytics

Tags: wordpress, facebook, google-analytics, facebook-instant-articles

I am running a WordPress which using Automattic/facebook-instant-articles-wp. 
But I realise the traffic tracked for IA showed in GA were unable to show the title.

A lot of website is recommending this for the GA code.

`<script>
            (function (i,s,o,g,r,a,m) {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function () {(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),                         m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','//www.google-   analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
            ga('create', 'ANALYTICS ID', 'auto');
            ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
            ga('set', 'campaignSource', 'Facebook');
            ga('set', 'campaignMedium', 'Social Instant Article');
            ga('send', 'pageview', {title: 'POST TITLE'});
        </script>`

Then it end up showing 'POST TITLE' in GA. Anyone have any clue to show the article title?

Thank you.

Comment: Where did you put this code in your theme?

Comment: @Dan9 At the analytics Embed code section for the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GA code like this should give you correct titles:

```
<script>
 ...
ga('create', 'XX-XXXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('set', 'campaignSource', 'Facebook');
ga('set', 'campaignMedium', 'Social Instant Article');
ga('set', 'title', 'IA - '+ia_document.title); // get your title 
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

So with ia_document.title you can get article title correct in analytics.

Here is a Facebook's reference to the issue:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/analytics#analytics-services

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The code that you've posted ends with:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {title: 'POST TITLE'});
```

This is why 'POST TITLE' is coming up in GA. By editing this field, you can decide how it will be reported to GA.

Comment: @J Brazier Opps. So sorry. I shall said. How can I change to the article title?

Comment: @CarsonLee Edit the Javascript to insert the article title there instead of the text string 'POST TITLE'

Comment: @J Brazier Cool. Can you show like how the javascript should be? Thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few answers that might be applicable here but I will show what requires the least modification here:

in your header:

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>  data-title="<?php echo get_the_title();?>">
```

You will need to replace your own logic for `get_the_title()` some pages created by use of rewrites will not have an title. But for most usage it will suffice.

```
<script>

            (function (i,s,o,g,r,a,m) {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function () {(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),                         m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','//www.google-   analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
            ga('create', 'ANALYTICS ID', 'auto');
            ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
            ga('set', 'campaignSource', 'Facebook');
            ga('set', 'campaignMedium', 'Social Instant Article');
            ga('send', 'pageview', {title: document.documentElement.getAttribute('data-title')});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using embed code and not sure what could be `POST TITLE`, you should try [`document.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title):

```
ga('send', {hitType: 'pageview', title: document.title});
```

See [page tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages) for more info. Remember to change `ANALYTICS ID` to actual ID too.